# Why can't I unban player?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm a beginner programmer and trying to make an admin system that includes kick, ban, and unban commands. After pressing unban button on a successfully banned user it tells me that the user was unbanned, but when I join the game from the banned user account it still says that I'm banned.

Code:

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    local ng = game.Workspace:FindFirstChild(plr.Name .. " / Banned")
    if ng:IsA("WedgePart") then
        plr:Kick("Banned")
        print(plr.Name .. " tried to join while banned")
    end
end)


script.Parent["Kick/Ban"].OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr, plrname, reason, kb)
    if game.Players:FindFirstChild(plrname) then
        local target = game.Players:FindFirstChild(plrname)
        if kb == "Kick" then
            if reason ~= "" then
                target:Kick(reason)
            elseif reason == "" then
                target:Kick()
            end
        elseif kb == "Ban" then
            local part = Instance.new("WedgePart")

            print(target.Name .. " has been banned")

            part.Parent = game.Workspace
            part.Name = target.Name .. " / Banned"
            part.CanCollide = false
            part.Transparency = 1
            part.Anchored = true
            
            target:Kick("Banned")
        elseif kb == "Unban" then
            local tn = plrname .. " / Banned"
            local part2 = game.Workspace:FindFirstChildOfClass("WedgePart")

            while part2 do
                if part2.Name:lower() == tn:lower() then
                    part2:Destroy()
                    print(target.Name .. " has been unbanned")
                    break
                end
                part2 = game.Workspace:FindFirstChildOfClass("WedgePart", part2)
            end

            if not part2 then
                print(target.Name .. " is not banned")
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

Tried asking AI for help but got nothing. I think the main problem is in `game.Players.PlayerAdded`. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to emphasise how bad of an idea using Instances to store data like this is, especially parts, since they can be influenced in a number of ways by other unrelated systems in your game.

You should instead have a variable set as a table inside your script that stores if players are banned or not, this also means that it would be trivial to enable bans saving over a server restart.

Something like the Below:

```lua
local bannedPlayers = {}

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    if bannedPlayers[plr.Name] then
        plr:Kick("Banned")
        print(plr.Name .. " tried to join while banned")
    end
end)


script.Parent["Kick/Ban"].OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr, plrname, reason, kb)
    if game.Players:FindFirstChild(plrname) then
        local target = game.Players:FindFirstChild(plrname)
        if kb == "Kick" then
            if reason ~= "" then
                target:Kick(reason)
            elseif reason == "" then
                target:Kick()
            end
        elseif kb == "Ban" then
            print(target.Name .. " has been banned")

            bannedPlayers[plrname] = reason
            target:Kick("Banned")
        elseif kb == "Unban" then
            if bannedPlayers[plrname] then
                bannedPlayers[plrname] = nil
                print(target.Name .. " has been unbanned")
            else
                print(target.Name .. " is not banned")
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

Comment: :) I'm glad, I didn't actually test it.

Answer (score 0):

I looked and didn't find anything wrong. I tried to tweak it a little try this code and see if it works:

```
script.Parent["Kick/Ban"].OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr, plrname, 
reason, kb)
    if game.Players:FindFirstChild(plrname) then
        local target = game.Players:FindFirstChild(plrname)
        if kb == "Kick" then
            if reason ~= "" then
                target:Kick(reason)
            elseif reason == "" then
                target:Kick()
            end
        elseif kb == "Ban" then
            local part = Instance.new("WedgePart")

            print(target.Name .. " has been banned")

            part.Parent = game.Workspace
            part.Name = target.Name .. " / Banned"
            part.CanCollide = false
            part.Transparency = 1
            part.Anchored = true
        
            target:Kick("Banned")
        elseif kb == "Unban" then
            local tn = plrname .. " / Banned"
            local part2 = game.Workspace:FindFirstChild(tn)

            if part2 then
                part2:Destroy()
                print(target.Name .. " has been unbanned")
            else
                print(target.Name .. " is not banned")
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

Comment: Sadly, doesnt work. Maybe problem is here? https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1192088216677912576/1199457390467235880/image.png?ex=65c29cbe&is=65b027be&hm=5fd8cc7d35c81ec72777db6634c5601bd9fd61f8c2a2f95c0d583296c694ef7b&

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).